# SQL order from x value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
id    title    display_order
9     t9       0
1     t1       3
2     t2       1
3     t3       5
4     t4       4
9     t9       0
10    t10      0
```

What I need is to have results like this

```
id    title    display_order
2     t2       1
1     t1       3
4     t4       4
3     t3       5
6     t6       0
9     t9       0
10    t10      0
```

I could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY
  display_order = 0,
  display_order
```

but unfortunelly I cant do this in SQL Sever 2014. Error appear on this line: `display_order = 0,`. Do you have any tips how can I do that in SQL server?

Comment: Was your question not answered?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY
  case when display_order = 0 then 1 else 0 end,
  display_order,
  id;
```

Comment: always nice to include more than just the SQL!  though this is about as simple as it gets!  (though shouldn't a 3rd sort be on id ?  what order do we want the 0's in?)  (not title as that would put t10 before t6.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY
  CASE display_order
    WHEN 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END ASC,
  display_order ASC
```

Comment: Right idea, but rows with display order = 0 need to come after the ones that <> 0, so should be ASC on the case statement rather than DESC.

Comment: @GarethLyons Thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! This is one of the features of SQL Server that just a few know about:

```
order by 
case when display_order = 0 then 1 else 0 end asc,
display_order asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can order this in two way,

1. Order the records with Zeros and non Zeros
2. Then Order the non Zero records respect to the Dislpay_Order.

So Use this following Code to Order that

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN display_order = 0 then 1 else 0 end, display_order;
```